# Command to run powershell functions in node-powershell package

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I am trying to load the ps.command to excute powershell functions ,were i need to load the ps file first and then execute my function.

ps.addCommand(". .\New-SecurePassword.ps1)  ///file name
ps.addCommand("New-Password) ///function name

```
function App(){
// Create the PS Instance
    let ps = new powershell({
        executionPolicy: 'unrestricted',
        noProfile: true
    })
   ps.addCommand(". .\New-SecurePassword.ps1")
   ps.addCommand("New-Password.ps1")
  ps.invoke()
    .then(output => {
      console.log(output);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
return App();
```

I am getting following error

```
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ . .New-SecurePassword.ps1
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.New-SecurePassword.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: As the backslash doesn't appear in the error message, it seems to need escaping with another one `ps.addCommand(". .\\New-SecurePassword.ps1")`

Comment: ``` const Oauthfile = `${__dirname}/Powershellscripts/. .\\New-SecurePassword.ps1`;
        //console.log(Oauthfile)
        ps.addCommand(Oauthfile)
        debugger;
      ps.addCommand('New-Password') ```     facing the same issue if call with const path